# polluntil undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, leadfoot

I have the following code:

```
define(function(require) {
    function myclass(remote) {
        this.remote = remote;
    }

myclass.prototype = {
    constructor: myclass,

.....

create_campaign: function() {
    var name = 'mycampaign';
    this.camapaignName = name.concat((Math.random()*1000).toString())

    return this.remote
        .findByXpath('//*[@id="new_campaign"]/button')
            .click()
            .end()
        .then(this.remote.pollUntil(function() {
            return (document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-user-plus').length == 1) ? true : null;
        },10000))
        .then(function() {
            return true;
        });
```

Intern keeps on giving me

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

When I try to assign pollUntil to a variable and call it, it still gives me the same error. I'm using the latest versions of Chromedriver/Chrome/etc.

Comment: What makes you think `this.remote.pollUntil` should exist?

Comment: I am assuming that since "this.remote" is a command object, it has the pollUntil() method available to be used.

Comment: Dunno, the docs show that it is included explicitly: https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/pollUntil.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the code in the AMD defines:

```
var pollUntil = require('intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil');
```